# Self generated java file implementing STAX to parse XML files using available xsd

Tags: java, xml

I have about 100 xml files each around 5MB. I have an xsd. Is there a way to generate a java class that will parse these files using the xsd I have ?

Is there any tool that can do this? or will I have to code this thing by hand ?

JAXB+STAX is not an option. I need to do it by STAX alone.

I will name my second born son after you if you can help me out.